# VBA　値の取得と配列への格納について

Tags: vba

以下のコードでセルの値を配列に格納する処理をおこなっていますが、`Debug.Print ary(j, 1)` で確認しても値が表示されない（取得できていない）ようです。

```
ary = Array(Cells(j, "E").Value, Cells(j, "F").Value, Cells(j, "G").Value, Cells(j, "H").Value, Cells(j, "I").Value)
```

下記のコードで何が間違いなのでしょう？エラー等は発生しておりません。

```
Dim j As Long
Dim ary As Variant

For j = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(j, "J").Value = "JST" Then
        ary = Array(Cells(j, "E").Value, Cells(j, "F").Value, Cells(j, "G").Value, Cells(j, "H").Value, Cells(j, "I").Value)
        Debug.Print ary(j, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: IFの判定がTrueになってないのだと思われますが、そのコードをどこに書いていますか？シートの指定がないCellsは、どこに書くかで参照するシートが変わります。I

Comment: コードは断片だけでなく、問題を再現できるように全体を質問文に含めてください。

Answer (score 0):

> 下記のコードで何が間違いなのでしょう？エラー等は発生しておりません。

`Debug.Print ary(j, 1)`で「インデックスが有効範囲にありません。」のエラーが発生するはずですが。
どこかに `On Error Resume Next`当のエラーを無視するコードを記述してませんか。しているなら、まずはそれをコメントアウトしましょう。

エラーの原因は、Array関数は一次元配列を返しますので、aryは一次元配列になります。
にもかかわらず、`ary(j, 1)`と二次元配列として扱っているので上記のエラーになります。

`Debug.Print ary(0)`
とすれば配列の先頭の値(=Cells(j, "E").Value)が表示されます。

やりたいことが、E～I列の1行目からLastRowまでの範囲を配列に格納したいということなら、ループせずとも下記の1行で可能です。

```vb
   Dim LastRow As Long
   LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Row

   Dim ary() As Variant
   ary = Range(Cells(1,"E"),Cells(LastRow,"I")).Value

   '配列の1列目(E列)の値の確認
   Dim i
   For i = 1 to LastRow
       Debug.Print ary(i, 1)
   Next
```

ちなみに、上記のようにValueで代入した配列は、インデックスが1から始まります。
Array関数は0から始まります。

Comment: On Error Resume Next は記載していません。
for文自体が実行されていないようです。
Debug.Print ary(0)を行っても、何も表示されません。

Comment: LastRowに最終行を代入するコードがないからでは。LastRowの取得法は回答のコードを参考にしてください。

Comment: `LastRow = Cell(Rsows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`は事前に取得しております。

Comment: 質問のコードは E列からJ列までを対象にしているのに、なぜA列の最終行なのでしょうか。どちらにしてコードの一部だけを見せられても原因の特定はむずかしいです。

Comment: 私の回答のコードは試しましたか。このコードではご希望とは異なりますか。もしそうなら、どのような結果をお望みですか。